# Пытаюсь сделать бота для майнкрафта на python mineflayer

Tags: javascript, python, minecraft

Я взял пример для бота на python (https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer/blob/master/examples/python/basic.py)
Изменил host на localhost и port на 50650(порт для майнкрафт сервера) [image: Вот так]

при запуске выдаёт ошибку:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f40d' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>
```

Полная ошибка:

```
`Started mineflayer
[JSE] node:internal/process/promises:246

[JSE]           triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);

[JSE]           ^

[JSE] 

[JSE] Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\javascript\events.py", line 170, in loop
    inbounds = connection.readAll()
  File "C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\javascript\connection.py", line 108, in readAll
    ret = read_stderr(stderr_lines)
  File "C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\javascript\connection.py", line 70, in read_stderr
    print("[JSE]", line)
  File "C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f40d' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>`
```

Хочу узнать что означает эта ошибка

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `localhost` на `https://localhost`